# 502 gateway error for AWS ALB using ACM

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

### Scenario

Trying to configure end to end ssl encryption from ALB to Spring boot application.

### Steps Done

#### ACM created

- created a domain name in ACM and downloaded the public certificate chain using `GetCertificateRequest` API.
  Domain name is `*.mnkartik.com`
- create a truststore.jks and imported the certificates and chain as trusted sources.

#### spring boot application on ec2

- configure the ALB with the target source as EC2
- created self signed certificate and keystore as keystore.jks
- configured the application as below in properties

```
    server.port=8080
    server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
    server.ssl.key-store-password = password
    server.ssl.key-password = password
    server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore.jks
    server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```

- when hit using the EC2 public api to spring boot application running on 8080 with https:// its working with an unsecured error ( as obvious ) with response printed successfully.

### Problem

But when hitting the alb url, its returning as 502 Bad gateway error. Could not be able to solve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is ec2 result

[image]

ALB result

[image]

Comment: Please add the ALB information, including all listener configuration and current target states.

Comment: Have added the listeners and also checked the health status, its `healthy`

Comment: @MarkB Added few more screenshots

Comment: You're showing your EC2 result twice, instead of showing the ALB result in the second screenshot. Have you checked the ALB logs?

Comment: I have configured the ALB logs to s3 but all I am seeing is just a single line as requested nothing related to SSL. For this created a bucket and gave permissions. does any full blown logs copied in s3 bucket ? I have shutdown the servers now, so wont be accessbile if urls are hit. But if any such ssl error logs are logged let know I will configure accordingly ( in case my approach to log configuration for alb is incorrect ). Thanks @Mark

Comment: You have to point your domain at the ALB. An SSL certificate is for a specific domain. In your screenshot you aren't loading that domain, you are loading the ALB's default address, which doesn't match your SSL certificate domain.